# logrotate not able to truncate catalina.out

Tags: centos, logrotate, tomcat

I'm running tomcat server in my centos machine. I've following content in my `/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat` file:

```
/log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out{
 copytruncate
 daily
 size 256M
 rotate 8
 missingok
 maxage 7
}
```

I tried to run the `logrotate` command manually in debug mode.

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

In the logs, I found following content regarding the `/log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out` file.

> rotating pattern: /log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out 268435456 bytes (8 rotations)
>
> empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
>
> considering log /log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out
>     log needs rotating
>
> rotating log /log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out, log->rotateCount is 8
>
> dateext suffix '-20190206'
>
> glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
>
> glob finding old rotated logs failed
>
> copying /log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out to /log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out-20190206
>
> truncating /log/apache-tomcat/catalina.out

But the file size didn't change after running the command. I'm not sure what went wrong here.  This file size is keep on increasing and causing lot of issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem got resolved after changing the permissions of `/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat` file.

Before:

```
$ ls -lht /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 308 Apr 25  2018 /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat
```

After:

```
$ sudo chmod -x /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat
$ ls -lht /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 308 Apr 25  2018 /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat
```

Got to know about it after checking verbose of `logrotate`.

```
$ /usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. Why would removing the X permission from the config file change anything?

Comment: I don't remember the issue with file permission. Like I mentioned, I got to know about this with `logrotate -v`.